# Create new column of specific values from other columns

Tags: r, find, dataset

I have county data but I want to create column that just lists the states. Basically, I have this:

```
County       
County 1, NY  
County 2, NY    
County 3, NY
County 4, TX
County 5, TX
County 6, IL
County 7, IL
```

But I want this:

```
County          State 
County 1, NY     NY
County 2, NY     NY
County 3, NY     NY
County 4, TX     TX
County 5, TX     TX
County 6, IL     IL
County 7, IL     IL
```

Is there a way to have R 'find' and select the "NY", "TX" etc in my County column and create a State column from that? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
dat$State <- gsub(".*\\b([^[:space:]]+)[[:space:]]*$", "\\1", dat$County)
dat
#         County State
# 1 County 1, NY    NY
# 2 County 2, NY    NY
# 3 County 3, NY    NY
# 4 County 4, TX    TX
# 5 County 5, TX    TX
# 6 County 6, IL    IL
# 7 County 7, IL    IL
```

Walk-through:

- `.*` is zero or more of something, here so that we can discard it
- `\\b` is a word-boundary, to make sure we get all of the state, not just its second letter
- `(...)` is a group that we'll recall later; anything in the parens in the first string can be referenced in the second string by its position, as in `\\1`
- `[^[:space:]]+` is a character-class, the `[:space:]` means any space-like thing, and `[^...]` negates that, so this means anything non-blank-space; the trailing `+` means one-or-more
- `[[:space:]]*` is a not-negated blank-space character class as before, but now the `*` means zero-or-more
- `$` is the end-of-string

---

Data

```r
dat <- structure(list(County = c("County 1, NY", "County 2, NY", "County 3, NY", "County 4, TX", "County 5, TX", "County 6, IL", "County 7, IL")), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: wow, thank you for the quick response and the walk through! super helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If your data for all the rows is exactly as shown you can delete everything until last comma and whitespace followed by it.

```
df$County <- sub('.*,\\s', '', df$County)
```

---

If the state names can be present anywhere in the data we can use the inbuilt constant `state.abb` and create a pattern with it to extract data if present anywhere in the `county` column.

```
library(stringr)
df$State <- str_extract(df$County, str_c(state.abb, collapse = '|'))
```

Comment: thank you so much!!! the first case is true for me but the second part is really good to know.

Comment: I find simpler patterns like that really appealing ... and then I find some data-entry somewhere forgot a comma or something else ... humans are horribly unreliable components of data-entry/-processing. :-)

Answer (score 0):

We can use `str_remove`

```
library(stringr)
df$State <- str_remove(df$County, ".*,\\s+")
```